# Visual Studio 2010 C++: malloc()/HeapAlloc always allocates new page for even smallest alloc size

Tags: c++, c, visual-studio-2010, memory-management

I have a rather large C/C++ project, and I have been trying to track down why it consumes an inordinate amount of memory (judged by the "Working Set" in the Task Manager).
I finally tracked it down to the bizarre behavior that, even for the smallest malloc() requests, it will allocate a full new 4k page.
Code like this

```
    for(int bla = 0; bla < 1000; bla++)
    {
        char* blu = (char*)malloc(10);
    }
```

which should increase memory consumption by a measly 10KB, ends up racking it up by 4MB, since it does 1000 4kB allocations.

The really frustrating part is that I can't reproduce it as standalone. A small app just with the above code works fine. Only the big project exhibits the wrong behavior.
To answer some obvious suggestions right upfront:

- I am pulling in the same libraries as the big project, and also made sure the compilation flags are the same
- "new" behaves the same way
- It happens both in Debug and Release mode
- I really tracked it down to the HeapAlloc call which is the culprit. Sadly one can't step into HeapAlloc to investigate further.

Any ideas? I am totally stumped.

Comment: Just fyi whoever is reading this question and its answers later, this was not the issue (it was the heap page issue). The debug heap can do "padding" of mem allocs to detect buffer over/underruns, but it would never inflate mem allocation by a factor 1,000, like the page heap does.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Windows includes a feature called "[Page Heap](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/ff549561.aspx)" which is helpful in locating memory corruption defects. It operates by placing each allocation on a page, which causes the processor to issue an access violation if the program corrupts memory instead of entering undefined behavior territory.

Sounds like somewhere in your big application someone has turned on page heap, or you have triggered some kind of application compatibility setting in Windows in your big application that enabled Page Heap.

Note that this is a Windows setting (HeapAlloc is a Win32 API), not a debug/release compiler setting.

Comment: Wow, thanks a million for your reply! It was actually a registry issue in the end, where my application was flagged as having page heap enabled. After deleting the registry entry it works normally now.